# How to use swap less often?

Tags: memory, swap, cache, ram

I use an SSD swap just to avoid full memory related crashes. There are limited erasures that can occure on SSDs. The memory related crashes have stopped, but my system uses swap constantly and `vmstat` shows in almost any period of time si and so != 0. I have changed my `/etc/sysctl.conf` to try to reduce the use of swap and increase pressure to dump cache, but I still find swap is used when there are Gbs of memory available.

I have already made some changes to try to reduce swap use:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
1
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/vfs_cache_pressure
200
```

There is a temporary solution to force swap into the cache in this [ask ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357/how-to-empty-swap-if-there-is-free-ram), but this is not useful when I am not actively monitoring memory.

OS: Pop 20.04 focal,
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.11.0-7612-generic

Comment: I've been running swapless for over 15 years now. Yes, I've had more than enough RAM but even if you don't, you could use something like `earlyoom` to avoid stalls/freezes in case you're really low on RAM.

Comment: I was running swapless for ages, but then I had a few memory based freeze ups so I had to revert :( Probably a more sensible fix is more RAM! Thanks for the earlyoom tip.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you delve deeper in to the *underlying* issue, the problem you are *really* trying to resolve, and other solutions for *that* issue. Or at least, better understand how the OS utilizes swap space.

Many people assume, incorrectly, that SWAP space is only used when free RAM is *needed*. Generally speaking (I am not certain about the Linux kernel!), an OS with swap space will swap out blocks of RAM which it sees have not been recently *accessed*: Very few algorithms will check if the swap is *needed* because RAM is full, only if the RAM has not been recently *accessed*. Thus, if you leave the system idle for awhile, RAM which has not been accessed because the system has been idle and certain programs are not accessing parts of their memory space, the OS will still swap out parts of that RAM even when there is still plenty of free RAM.

[This is illustrated by this question over on *Ask Ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357/how-to-empty-swap-if-there-is-free-ram), where the user experiences the OS swapping large parts of RAM to swap space while leaving their system idle for days--then experiences poor system performance for awhile after returning and using the system again and the OS is trying to restore used/accessed blocks of RAM which are once again being accessed regularly.

One approach, if you can use it, is to not use the SSD for swap space at all. In my desktop, I have an old 500GB non-SSD hard drive with a swap partition I use.

Another method would be a performance trade-off: Create a cron job for a script that runs every minute and checks RAM use. When RAM use is above 60%, it uses `swapon` (with appropriate parameters) to use a swap *file* in case it is needed. When RAM use drops back below 40%, it then uses `swapoff` to disable the use of the swap file and let the OS "drain" the swap back in to physical RAM. Of course, you will need a previously created and properly initialized swap file to enable/disable. (And make the thresholds different... If you set them both to the same value such as 50%, you will experience *thrashing* when the RAM use hovers between slightly above 50% and slightly below 50%. Fine tune the values to how you typically use the system.)

I am sure there are other methods and techniques used by others, as well. Likewise, as the use of SSD drives increases, the kernel algorithms will likely be modified to use SSD-based swap partitions less unless absolutely needed.

Comment: Thanks! The cron approach is interesting, but might encourage more erasures than leaving it be which is the real thing that degrades the SSD. I think HDD might be a good solution for now. The system is online for months at a time, hence swap and cache are much higher than usual.

Comment: The cron approach won't trigger though unless RAM usage is above the threshold. At that point, yes, it may trigger a lot of writes... which it is already doing as-is. The intent is to make it not use a swap file or swap space *at all* when RAM usage is below the threshold: No swap == No disk writes -- "law of averages" type trade-off. There are other issues, however, so as long as you have a secondary disk to use for swap partitions/files, that is the solution you should use. Laptops and embedded devices are the main issue where a secondary drive is not an option.

Comment: (And to add, the swap file approach does not erase the swap file, so there is no "write to delete" it; It just tells the kernel to stop using it.)